# Can we get token name from web3.py by providing the contract address?

Tags: web3py

For example, can we get 'USDC' returned by providing its contract address 0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Web3.py](https://pypi.org/project/web3/) module:

```
from web3 import Web3
import json

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://rpc.ankr.com/eth'))

abi = [{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
address = '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48'
   
contract = web3.eth.contract(address , abi = abi)

token_name = contract.functions.name().call() 
token_symbol = contract.functions.symbol().call() 

print('Name:', token_name)
print('Symbol:', token_symbol)
```

For more examples, you can refer [this](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) docs.